# Gerência de processos no SO

Tags: sistema-operacional, processo

Para o Sistema Operacional, um processo independentemente do seu estado é um programa em execução?

A pergunta da prova era de **verdadeiro** ou **falso**. Eu escolhi **falso**, mas a resposta estava errada. Alguém pode me explicar o porquê?

Comment: Creio que a pergunta ficou mal formulada. Ela poderia ser melhor explorada pelo seu professor, como por exemplo, falar se o SO em questão é mono ou multi thread.

Comment: porque foi correta?

Comment: coloca um `>` na frente do Para o sistema, evidencia melhor.

Comment: Porque a definição de processos são tarefas em execução, ou seja, ele precisa assumir o estado de "EXECUTANDO" para assumir o tal papel.

Comment: Analisando a resposta do @OnoSendai, creio que a pergunta também foi mal formulada. Mas enfim, fica a critério do professor e da turma.

Comment: @rray Eu não vejo motivo para fazer isso, a rigor o `>` é para citações.

Comment: Acho que faltou um par de virgulas. Eu acho que a pergunta é: "Para o Sistema Operacional, um processo, independentemente do seu estado, é um programa em execução?"

Comment: @bfavaretto, me pareceu adequado por se tratar de algo externo, ou seja, não foi o OP que formulou a pergunta se tem alguma coisa errada não foi por parte dele, por isso sugeri, se não é aplicavel nesse contexto não tem problema :)

Comment: Não tinha pensado por esse lado, @rray. Na verdade funciona dos dois jeitos mesmo.

Comment: Eu copiei a questão da prova. Ela estava escrita dessa forma.

Answer (score 1):

Em sistemas multitarefa, apenas quando um processo tem suas instruções interpretadas e executadas pelo processador é que seu estado é chamado 'sob execução'.

[Existem vários estados possíveis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_state) - 'em espera', 'bloqueado' e 'criado', entre outros. Nenhum destes é considerado 'sob execução'.

Por este ponto de vista, me parece que seu professor está correto.